# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server after installing apache2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to install apache2 on my Ubuntu 17.10 using this command:

`sudo apt-get install -y apache2`

at the end of the installation it fails with:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status apache2.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-02-07 13:38:15 EET; 6ms ago
  Process: 10516 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1403 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      CPU: 14ms

feb 07 13:38:15 username1-Latitude-5480 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
feb 07 13:38:15 username1-Latitude-5480 apachectl[10516]: apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory
feb 07 13:38:15 username1-Latitude-5480 apachectl[10516]: Action 'start' failed.
feb 07 13:38:15 username1-Latitude-5480 apachectl[10516]: The Apache error log may have more information.
feb 07 13:38:15 username1-Latitude-5480 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
feb 07 13:38:15 username1-Latitude-5480 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
feb 07 13:38:15 username1-Latitude-5480 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
feb 07 13:38:15 username1-Latitude-5480 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

80 port is free

what need I do to install apache2 without failures?

Answer (score 2):

```
Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
```

Please test if there is a conf and which owner is set